# How can we Get the Latest timestamp by comparing the timestamp dynamically in WSO2

Tags: javascript, wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-micro-integrator

How to get the latest timestamp by comparing the timeStamp received from soap dynamically with the latest timestamp by using Script mediator.
Input will be like `2018-04-26T05:59:38.226-07:00`

```
<iterate expression="/Customer" id="" sequential="true">
                <target>
                    <sequence>
<property expression="CustomerID" name="CUS_ID_TO_UPDATE" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
<property expression="UpdateDate" name="LATEST_DATE" scope="default" type="STRING" />
</propertyGroup>
<script language="js"><![CDATA[
var log                = mc.getServiceLog();
var simpleDateFormat   = Packages.java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
var Customer_Id        = mc.getProperty('CUS_ID_TO_UPDATE');
var Updated_Date       = mc.getProperty('LATEST_DATE');
var format             = new simpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
var Time               = format.parse(Updated_Date);
var Latest_Updated_Date = "";
var Latest_Customer_Id  ="";
if (Time.getTime()>Latest_Updated_Date) 
{
Latest_Updated_Date = Time;
Latest_Customer_Id = Customer_Id;
}
else
{
Latest_Updated_Date;
Latest_Customer_Id;
}
log.info(Latest_Updated_Date);
log.info(Latest_Customer_Id);   
​
mc.setProperty('Date',Latest_Updated_Date);
mc.setProperty('ID',Latest_Customer_Id);]]></script>
<log>
<property expression="get-property('Date')" name="Date"/>
<property expression="get-property('ID')" name="ID"/>
</log>
                </sequence>
            </target>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/time" name="Time" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST">
        <inSequence>
            <property expression="//time1/text()" name="time1" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property expression="//time2/text()" name="time2" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <script language="nashornJs"><![CDATA[
            var time1 = mc.getProperty("time1");
            var time2 = mc.getProperty("time2"); 
            var eTime1 = new Date(time1).getTime();
            var eTime2 = new Date(time2).getTime();
            if(eTime1 > eTime2) {
                mc.setProperty("latestTime", time1);
            } else {
                mc.setProperty("latestTime", time2);
            }]]></script>
            <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                <format>
                    <LatestTime>$1</LatestTime>
                </format>
                <args>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:latestTime"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

**Request**

```xml
<request>
    <time1>2018-04-26T05:58:38.226-07:00</time1>
    <time2>2018-04-26T05:59:38.226-06:00</time2>
</request>
```

**Response**

```xml
<LatestTime>2018-04-26T05:59:38.226-06:00</LatestTime>
```

Comment: i'll receive the timestmap dynamically by hitting the other api and i'll receive the response timestamp by comparing the timestamp dynamically i need to get the latest time stamp in my proxy

Comment: @sathishSankarzz I'm not understanding your question. Doesn't the above address your requirement?

Comment: By using iterate mediator i'll receive the timestamp dynamically 
By  hitting the api i'll get only one timestamp so by using iterate i'll receive multiple timestamp and i need to compare that timestamp and need to get the latest timestamp

Comment: @sathishSankarzz It doesn't really matter from where you get the time stamp, have the above login in the Iterate and pass the two timestamps you get and get the latest one.

Comment: I'll receive only 1 timestmap from my Xml file by using that i need to iterate and i need to get the latest timestamp

Comment: var temp=0;

function dateCompare(d1){
var time = new Date(d1);
var max = time.getTime();

for( var i=max-1;i<max+1;i++)
{
if(max>temp)
{
  temp= max;
}
else
{
  max;
}
}
console.log(new Date(temp));
}

dateCompare("2022-12-27")
dateCompare("2023-11-26")

Based on JavaScript code i was trying in Intergration Studio but in WSO2 it was not able to Compare the latest date